# splitting beamer frame vertical into two frames (with frametitle)

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I would like to split one frame into two frames located next to each other. Basicaly I could do this using minipage or columns (as the example shows)...However in this case I will lose some space from skipping the `frametitle`.

This is how it might work (not what I am looking for)

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{~}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle} left frame title}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle} right frame title}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

But I actually want somehting like:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitleleft{left frame title}
    \frametitleright{right frame title}

    \leftcontent{..}
    \rightcontent{...}
\end{frame}
```

I am hoping you understand what exactly I am trying to achieve.

EDIT: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294987/splitting-frame-title?rq=1) kind of addresses what I am looking for, but not exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could temporarily switch to a custom frametitle template, that supports two titles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{splitframe}[3][]{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
  \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}%
      \usebeamercolor{frametitle}%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \strut #2%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}%
      \usebeamercolor{frametitle}%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \strut #3%
  \end{minipage}%
  \vskip-1ex%  
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[splitframe]{left frametitle}{right frametitle}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{foo} % <- needs to be non-empty, content does not matter
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        left frame text
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        right frame text
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems convinient. `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` initiate a seperate enviroment to ensure the custom frametemplate will be only used within?

Comment: Did not specify, but does this solution provide a way to ensure the `titlesection` will be shown?

Comment: @Djiwahwah Yes, the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` ensure that not all frames are affected, but only the ones you want.

Comment: @Djiwahwah What do you mean with `titlesection`?

Comment: Well I am using an outertheme of my university. 
And only if a frametitle is provided there is the section name and number above the frametitle. 
As we are supressing the framtitle of this frame, there is obviously nothing like this.
It could be a theme thing, but I imagened this is standard beamer behaviour.

Comment: @Djiwahwah That is certainly not a standard beamer behaviour. Probably a similar framtitle definition could be made based on your custom theme.

Comment: Alright thats no biggie, I guess I might be able to take look myself using what you've provided. Not that urgent anyway. Thanks.