# Two frame titles, each for column, in one slide

Tags: beamer

I would like two title frames above of each column as in the picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}                   % Document class
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set encoding
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % For table rules
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]   % Set caption to 
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

\begin{frame}{Literature Review}
\small
\vspace{-0.4cm}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
         \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
         \item<1-> M\&A literature overwhelmingly focuses on testing neoclassical and behavioural theories.
         \item<1-> Previous studies overlooked the dynamics of market power, overlooking post-M\&A firms relative position in terms of markups, share of profits or market share.
         \vspace{-0.3cm}
            \item<2-> Difficulties in coming out with reliable counterfactuals.
                \vspace{-0.1cm}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item<4-> Post-M\&A assessment in terms of counterfactual based on theories to be tested.
                \end{itemize}
            
        \end{itemize}

        \vspace{-0.4cm}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<5-> There has been a bias in the periods studied:
            \begin{itemize}
                    \item<6-> \small Focused on Conglomerates M\&A Wave in the 1960s and on the 'Donwsize and Distribute' 1980s.
                \end{itemize}
            \item<7-> Corporate financialization explains lower capex (SVO, financial turn of investment) but no attention paid to M\&As.
            \item<8-> Adding a link between firm-level behaviour to sector- and macro-level trends to rising markups literature (Guitierrez and Philippon, 2019; Autor et al., 2020; De Loecker et al., 2020).
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments. Always include a short, but compilable test document in your questions, which includes a class etc.

Comment: I think I added now the complete information.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471005/splitting-beamer-frame-vertical-into-two-frames-with-frametitle?noredirect=1&lq=1 would work.

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme Your code does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

You could fake the look of fametitles like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}                   % Document class
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set encoding
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % For table rules
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]   % Set caption to 
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \small
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}Frametitle 1\par}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> M\&A literature overwhelmingly focuses on testing neoclassical and behavioural theories.
        \item<1-> Previous studies overlooked the dynamics of market power, overlooking post-M\&A firms relative position in terms of markups, share of profits or market share.
        \item<2-> Difficulties in coming out with reliable counterfactuals.
        \begin{itemize}
          \item<4-> Post-M\&A assessment in terms of counterfactual based on theories to be tested.
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}Frametitle 2\par}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<5-> There has been a bias in the periods studied:
        \begin{itemize}
          \item<6-> \small Focused on Conglomerates M\&A Wave in the 1960s and on the `Donwsize and Distribute' 1980s.
        \end{itemize}
        \item<7-> Corporate financialization explains lower capex (SVO, financial turn of investment) but no attention paid to M\&As.
        \item<8-> Adding a link between firm-level behaviour to sector- and macro-level trends to rising markups literature (Guitierrez and Philippon, 2019; Autor et al., 2020; De Loecker et al., 2020).
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]